# Solve the eikonal equation with radial data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

Consider the equation
$$
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\right)^{2} + \frac{1}{r^{2}}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \varphi}\right)^{2} = g(r).
$$
How to solve it? Here the left hand side is $|\nabla f|^2$ in polar coordinates.

After separating the variables, I get 
$$\sqrt{g(r)r^{2} - r^{2} (\partial_{r} f)^{2} } = \partial_{\varphi} f$$

Comment: This looks like an eikonal equation and has a very general solution.  Do you have a context and/or a set of boundary conditions that could help guide a solution?

Comment: No, I don't. I only have an equation in cartesian coordinate system, which I rewrite into an equation in a Polar system.

Comment: Try a separation of variables at this point?

Comment: What do you mean in this case?

Comment: Oh, thank you. After separation I can get

$$
\sqrt{g(r)r^{2} - r^{2} (\partial_{r} f)^{2} } = \partial_{\varphi} f.
$$
So, the left and the right side is equal to some constant a.

Answer (score 1):

An issue with separation of variables is that with a nonlinear PDE, there is no way to construct the general solution by summing separated solutions. But if the goal is to find just one solution, then looking for a separated one is a good idea. If both sides in 
$$\sqrt{g(r)r^{2} - r^{2} (\partial_{r} f)^{2} } = \partial_{\varphi} f$$ 
are constant, then the constant has to be zero because a nonzero constant value of $\partial_{\varphi} f$ would make $f$ multi-valued. From here $f$ can be found...

But it would be simpler to just assume from the outset that $f$ is radial (looking for a radial solution with radial data is natural). So $f=f(r)$, and the equation is simply $f'(r)=\sqrt{g(r)}$.