# solving a nonlinear PDE with partial derivatives in squares

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Are there any existing methods to solve a system of nonlinear PDE that looks like this:
$$\left(\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x} \right)^2 = g(x,t)$$

where $g(x,t)$ is going to be specified?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution for a first order non-linear partial differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3610086/solution-for-a-first-order-non-linear-partial-differential-equation)

Comment: @Gonçalo Hmm... Will check it out. But it seems to work only for spatial derivatives. But I'll try to see if I can make it work with the del operator replaced by a D'Alembertian. Will get back to you. Thanks for pointing me to that question!